# Center Bootstrap Navbar and Right-Justify Navbar Items?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstrap v3.3.4, I'd like to have my navbar centered to the main content on the screen (instead of sticking to the left) while having the navbar items appear right-justified within that centered area. Can this be done?

Here's the page I'm working on:
http://test.scoe.net/exmpl/register.html#

Comment: Welcome to SO! You need to attempt this, post the code you try, and any problems you are having so that we may help you with said issues. See the [How to ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help in improving your question.

Comment: Please don't point at some random place, the questions (and answers) are supposed to last a long time, webpages come and go.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question just place the div containing your menu item inside a `nav` and a `container` . For the second in `ul set`navbar-right` class

like this

```
            <nav  class="navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar" role="navigation">
              <div class="container"><div class="navbar-header">
                   .........
                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="........" >YourBrand</a>
                </div>
                  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right nav">
                      <li><a href="yoursite/index">Home</a></li>
                      <li><a href="yoursitesite/about">About</a></li>
                      <li><a href="yoursitesite/contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </nav>
```